# Changing font-family of maven-javadoc-plugin

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

Can I specific font-family that use to generate apidocs while I use command mvn site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a custom stylesheet file in your maven plugin configuration.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
      <stylesheetfile>${basedir}/path/to/your/stylesheetfile.css</stylesheetfile>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```